# Back-light control for dual screen laptop

Tags: ubuntu, monitors, asus, backlight

I've recently installed Pop!_OS on my new Asus Zenbook Pro Duo - UX581G.

This laptop has 2 built-in displays and they work out of the box on linux just fine, at least for the most part. Using xrandr I am able to see the first display is identified as eDP-1-1 and the second display as DP-1-2.

The main display is an OLED touchscreen, so the default brightness controls don't work out of the box on Linux. I can adjust the brightness using xrandr or ICC profiles, even tho this is not perfect, as it washes out the colors at lower brightness settings, but it's still better then nothing and even lower power consumption, because OLED.

The second display is an IPS panel, so technically speaking, it should have ACPI enabled backlight control, which would allow for brightness control without washing out colors and even turning off the backlight completely to conserve power. Using the xrandr or ICC method on this display won't have any effect on power either, since it's IPS it will consume just as much at 0% as it would at 100%.

When I check my `/sys/class/backlight` folder, it contains only one `intel_backlight` reference, but this seems to be the one that's supposed to control the display on `eDP-1`, which is the main OLED display.

My question: how do I make linux recognize the backlight control on the internal `DP-1` connection as well, as currently it only recognizes the one on `eDP-1`, almost as if it thinks the `DP-1` is an external monitor and thus doesn't support brightness control.

I've already looked into other solutions like `ddccontrol` but laptop displays don't support `DDC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind people in this thread have figured it out https://github.com/s-light/ASUS-ZenBook-Pro-Duo-UX581GV/issues/1

Now we can adjust backlight brightness using a kernel patch

Comment: If that link provides a solution, can you please edit your answer to explain the solution? Otherwise, this will just be deleted since it isn't really answering the question.

Comment: I was actually part of that thread at the time, forgot I actually posted a question here as well!

For those who don't want to go through the entire thread, the following repository contains the instructions to install the custom kernel module.

https://github.com/Plippo/screenpad-tools

Answer (score 0):

This gui is the only one working for my Asus Zenbook Pro Duo i9 10th gen UX581:

`https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller-simple
```

Answer (score 0):

The [asusZenBookProDuoScreenBrightnessService](https://github.com/rayperea/asusZenBookProDuoScreenBrightnessService) may help.

It's only been tested on Arch Linux, but depending on your level of knowledge, you may be able to adapt it.